# Comparison between numpy.all and bitwise '&' for binary sequence

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a problem to perform a bitwise '&' between two large binary sequences of the same length and I need to find the indexes where the 1's appear.

I used numpy to do it and here is my code:

```
>>> c = numpy.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]) #initialize 2d array
>>> c = c.all(axis=0)
>>> d = numpy.where(c)[False] #returns indices
```

I checked the timings for it.

```
>>> print("Time taken to perform 'numpy.all' : ",timeit.timeit(lambda :c.all(axis=0),number=10000))
>>> Time taken to perform 'numpy.all' :  0.01454929300234653
```

This operation was slower than what I expected.

Then, to compare, I performed a basic bitwise '&' operation:

```
>>> print("Time taken to perform bitwise & :",timeit.timeit('a = 0b0000000001111111111100000001111111111; b = 0b0000000001111111111100000001111111111; c = a&b',number=10000))

>>> Time taken to perform bitwise & : 0.0004252859980624635
```

This is much quicker than numpy

I'm using numpy because it allows to find the indexes where it has 1's, but the numpy.all operator is much slower.

My original data will be array list just like in first case. Will there be any repurcusion if I convert this list into a binary number and then perform the computation like in the second case?

Comment: These two operations are *not* equivalent, at least not the way you're calculating them.  They will produce two very different results

Comment: I used the numpy.random.randint(2, size=(2, 40)) because I thought it would take a lot of space to write down all the array elements

Comment: `numpy.random.randint(2, size=(2, 40))` is not a binary number. It is a `numpy.ndarray` object with shape `(2,40)`, and calling `numpy.all` on it is not doing the same thing as bitwise `&`

Comment: Hi All, I change my numpy array and initialized the values same as 'a' and 'b' in the second case. Still the timing is the same!

Comment: In what form do you have these "binary numbers"?  If the source is a bit string, the solution is pretty simple; if the numbers are in decimal form, then you'd have to convert them at some point.

Comment: Also, please note that you've edited this to be a question quite different from the original.  Please roll back your edit and post the new issue as a separate question.

Comment: Hi Prune, I've reverted back to the original question. And if I have bit strings, I assume that I have to convert it into decimal first, multiply them and convert back to string. That will also not work, since it will remove the leading zeros which are required for me. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can beat the speed of `a&b` (the actual computation is just a bunch of elementary cpu ops, I'm pretty sure the result of your `timeit` is >99% overhead). For example:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> k = 2**17-2
>>> a = random.randint(0, 2**k-1) + 2**k
>>> b = random.randint(0, 2**k-1) + 2**k
>>> timeit('a & b', globals=globals())
2.520026927930303
```

That's >100k bits and takes just ~2.5 us.

In any case the cost of `&` will be dwarfed by the cost of generating the list or array of indices.

`numpy` comes with significant overhead itself, so for a simple operation like yours one needs to check whether it is worth it.

So let's try a pure python solution first:

```
>>> c = a & b
>>> timeit("[x for x, y in enumerate(bin(c), -2) if y=='1']", globals=globals(), number=1000)
7.905808186973445
```

That's ~8 ms and as anticipated several orders of magnitude more than the `&` operation.

How about numpy?

Let's move the list comprehension first:

```
>>> timeit("np.where(np.fromstring(bin(c), np.uint8)[2:] - ord('0'))[0]", globals=globals(), number=1000)
1.0363857130287215
```

So in this case we get a ~8-fold speedup. This shrinks to ~4-fold if we require the result to be a list:

```
>>> timeit("np.where(np.fromstring(bin(c), np.uint8)[2:] - ord('0'))[0].tolist()", globals=globals(), number=1000)
1.9008758360287175
```

We can also let numpy do the binary conversion, which gives another small speedup:

```
>>> timeit("np.where(np.unpackbits(np.frombuffer(c.to_bytes(k//8+1, 'big'), np.uint8))[1:])[0]", globals=globals(), number=1000)
0.869781385990791
```

In summary:

- numpy is not always faster, better leave the `&` to pure Python
- locating nonzero bits seems fast enough in numpy to offset the cost of conversion between list and array

Please note that all this comes with the caveat that my pure Python code is not necessarily optimal. For example using a lookup table we can get a bit faster:

```
>>> lookup = [(np.where(i)[0]-1).tolist() for i in np.ndindex(*8*[2])]
>>> timeit("[(x<<3) + z for x, y in enumerate(c.to_bytes(k//8+1, 'big')) for z in lookup[y]]", globals=globals(), number=1000)
4.687953414046206
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> c = numpy.random.randint(2, size=(2, 40)) #initialize
>>> c
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Accessing this gives you two slow-downs:

- You have to access the two rows, whereas your bit-wise test has the constants readily available in registers.
- You are performing a series of 40 `and` operations, which *may* include casting from a full integer to a Boolean.

You severely handicapped the `all` test; the result is not a surprise (any more).

Comment: I initialized that with a constant array. Still the timings are the same. I have updated the variable in the question as well. Please let me know, if I need to change any other thing

Comment: The initialization method is not part of your timing, so that doesn't affect the question.

Comment: Could you please suggest any better approach to mine?

Answer (score 0):

The factor you observe is a direct consequence of the fact that `c=numpy.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]])` is an array on `int` and an `int` is coded in 32bits

therefore when you go c.all() you are doing an operation on 37*32 = 1184 bits

However `a = 0b0000000001111111111100000001111111111` is composed of 37 bits so when you do `a&b` the operation is on 37 bits.

therefore you are doing something 32 times more costly with the numpy array.

Let's test that

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
print("Time taken to perform bitwise & :",timeit.timeit('a=0b0000000001111111111100000001111111111; b = 0b0000000001111111111100000001111111111; c = a&b',number=320000))
a = 0b0000000001111111111100000001111111111
b = 0b0000000001111111111100000001111111111
c=np.array([a,b])
print("Time taken to perform 'numpy.all' : ",timeit.timeit(lambda :c.all(axis=0),number=10000))
```

the `&` operation I do 320000 times and the `all()` operation I do 10000 times.

```
Time taken to perform bitwise & : 0.01527938833025152
Time taken to perform 'numpy.all' :  0.01583387375572265
```

It's the same thing !

Now back to your initial problem you want to know the indices where bits are 1 in a large binary number.

Maybe you could try things provided by the bitarray module

```
a = bitarray.bitarray('0000000001111111111100000001111111111')
b = bitarray.bitarray('0000000001111111111100000001111111111')
i=0
data = list()
for c in a&b:
    if(c):
        data.append(i)
    i=i+1
print (data)
```

outputs

```
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
```